# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.thotheolh.jche.NativeBridge.loadPKCS11Module(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have looked through the UnsatisfiedLinkError helps in StackOverFlow and other search engines but the solutions have not satisfied the problem so I will state them here.

I am trying to make a JNI call to a PKCS11 DLL library and I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.thotheolh.jche.NativeBridge.loadPKCS11Module(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.thotheolh.jche.NativeBridge.loadPKCS11Module(Native Method)
at org.thotheolh.jche.NativeBridge.load(NativeBridge.java:40)
at org.thotheolh.jche.NativeBridge.<init>(NativeBridge.java:29)
at org.thotheolh.jche.exception.test.PKCS11GenericTest.main(PKCS11GenericTest.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

My native bridge snippet I used to do the 'native' calls below:

NativeBridge.java

```
public class NativeBridge {

private String pkcs11Module;
private String pkcs11JavaWrapper = "libJPKCS11";

public NativeBridge(String pkcs11Module) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException {
    this.pkcs11Module = pkcs11Module;
    load();
}

public void load() throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException {
    System.loadLibrary(pkcs11JavaWrapper);
    loadPKCS11Module(pkcs11Module);
}

public synchronized native void loadPKCS11Module(String location) throws IOException;
}
```

javah generated Header File snippet:

JCHE.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class org_thotheolh_jche_NativeBridge */

#ifndef _Included_org_thotheolh_jche_NativeBridge
#define _Included_org_thotheolh_jche_NativeBridge
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     org_thotheolh_jche_NativeBridge
 * Method:    loadPKCS11Module
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_thotheolh_jche_NativeBridge_loadPKCS11Module
 (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

C file snippet:

JCHE.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "JCHE.h"

const char *pkcs11ModuleFileLoc;
HMODULE pkcs11;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_thotheolh_jche_NativeBridge_loadPKCS11Module
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring location) {
    printf("inside native method\n");
    pkcs11ModuleFileLoc = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, location, (jboolean *)0);
    printf("%s", pkcs11ModuleFileLoc);
    //pkcs11 = LoadLibraryA(pkcs11ModuleFileLoc);
    //printf("\nLoaded PKCS11 Lib");
}
```

I have attempted to check the loaded libraries in Java and found them already loaded but somehow I am getting the described error despite looking through many other methods available to try and remedy this problem.

Comment: By the way, the JCHE.c is packaged as libJPKCS11.dll and classpath already set properly for those who wonder about the "private String pkcs11JavaWrapper = "libJPKCS11";" line of code in NativeBridge.java.

Comment: Please quote the error message ***accurately.*** Your title is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very old 2012 Netbeans post to solve the problem. It is due to a few GCC compiler options missing when making the DLL files.

Additional GCC Compiler Option:

```
-Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
```

Reference:
http://forums.netbeans.org/post-130319.html

Comment: That's what's called "built with the correct flags for creating a DLL". ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried and I cannot reproduce your problem (but I used Linux and changed `System.loadLibrary("libJPKCS11");` into `System.loadLibrary("JPKCS11");`, see below, but I'm sure that's not causing your problem because the error message would be different).

The error message that you get means the library could be loaded, so there's no problem with the call to `System.loadLibrary()`.

Are you sure that `JCHE.obj` is member of `libJPKCS11.dll`, i.e. `libJPKCS11.dll` is linked correctly, and that `JCHE.obj` is built with the correct flags for creating a DLL? To me, the message looks as if the library is loaded correctly, but does not contain function `Java_org_thotheolh_jche_NativeBridge_loadPKCS11Module()`. So, you might want to check whether `libJPKCS11.dll` actually is "complete" and "up-to-date".

By the way, you could consider removing the `lib` prefix. `System.loadLibrary` takes care of prefix and suffix. You would only use `System.loadLibrary("foo");`. It then loads `libfoo.so` on POSIX and `foo.dll` on Windows. Otherwise it would try to load `liblibfoo.so` on POSIX which feels strange.

Comment: The built DLL file is named "libJPKCS11.dll" deliberately. Does it have any impact ? I used a DLL viewing tool and it shows me the correct functions in the libJPKCS11.dll.

Comment: Changing the name of the DLL to JPKCS11.dll still doesn't fix it.

Comment: As I said, that's not the issue, that's just a suggestion. Check whether `JCHE.obj` is built properly and contained in `libJPKCS11.dll`.

Comment: I used dllexport.exe from nirsoft to view the DLL and it says:"Java_org_thotheolh_jche_NativeBridge_loadPKCS11Module@12 0x635c1280 0x00001280 69 (0x45) JPKCS11.dll C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JPKCS11\dist\JPKCS11.dll Exported Function". Seems like it is inside the DLL.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Sorry. If somebody else finds the problem, I'll delete my answer if someone else finds the problem.

Comment: Ha, I got one more idea what you could look into. It could be that Java somehow finds another DLL with the same name somewhere and loaded that. You can check that by giving your DLL a very very unique name. If it then fails to load the DLL, it was a path issue (`-Djava.library.path=...`). It it still has the same problem, it means this attempt of finding the cause failed, but at least the path is ruled out.